# Is there a Web Based Call Only Sample?

Tags: agora.io

I do not need Video, so no need to display a video image. The two examples I can find mix the display of the video with the setup/config of display and removing the code breaks the app.

Is there sample web/javascript example for sound only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agora Community github has this repo: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/tree/master/One-to-One-Video/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1

Although this is for video, in your code logic, you can set video = false to only allow audio in your app. Hopefully, it helps answer your question. :)